# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int (complex) of type 'numpy.float64'

Tags: python

I am trying to get a vector as mentioned in the image contain a complex number but I can't exceed this issue

```
v=1
 Frames=100
impulse_response[1:v ,: ] = (1 / np.sqrt(2 * v)) *(randn(v, Frames), 1j*randn(v, Frames))
```

the result that I want is
[image]

Comment: I think the output of ```(1 / np.sqrt(2 * v))``` is posing a problem. You are expected to multiply an ```int``` value but you are passing a ```float``` value.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i want to multiply by a float number to get a complex number like (0.5i -1.2) for example

Comment: Then you write it like this -  ```(1 / np.sqrt(2 * v)) *sum((randn(v, Frames), 1j*randn(v, Frames)))```

Comment: thank you now it works, i forgot to add the addition symbol.